# How can I center an image and also rescale it?

Tags: graphics

I have a document I am writing for my math class. I have this code here

```
\begin{center}
    \begin{figure}[!htb]
        \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{14-1Ex2.png}
    \end{figure}
\end{center}
```

that is supposed to recenter and rescale the image. However, I end up with something like this: 
[image: code result]

How can I get it to both center and rescale?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How's this?

```
\begin{figure}[!htb]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{14-1Ex2.png} % or put scale whatever you want
\end{figure}
```

Comment: That worked great! Thanks so much! What's the difference between this way and the way I was using?

Comment: [This page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2651/should-i-use-center-or-centering-for-figures-and-tables) might be useful!